Covariant faithful representations
It is well known that every C*-algebra admits a faithful representation into bounded operators on some Hilbert space. But, what happens in the equivariant world?
That is, given a topological group (not necessarily locally compact) $G$, and a $G$-C*-algebra $A$, does it admit a faithful covariant representation into bounded operators on some $G$-Hilbert space (that is, a Hilbert space equipped with a strongly continuous action of $G$ by unitaries)?
For locally compact groups, I think the regular representation associated to some faithful representation of $A$ should work. But I'm unsure about the general case.

Not sure either. You might need the existence of a nice measure on your group for this to be possible.

@Andromeda and does the regular representation indeed work for locally compact $G$?

Yes. It works. But that of course uses the Haar measure.

Can you give some reference? I see it clearly for discrete groups, but the general locally compact case looks tricky.

Uhm, try the book C*-algebras and their automorphism groups by Pedersen or the book ok Crossed products by Dana Williams.
